# TSQL XQuery filter to only select nodes that contain at least one character (or are non-numeric)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have the following XML.

```
<XML>   
    <Data>         
        <Outer>
            <Inner>123ABC</Inner>
        </Outer>
        <Outer>
            <Inner>123</Inner>
        </Outer>
        <Outer>
            <Inner>-123</Inner>
        </Outer>
    </Data>
</XML>
```

I want to select the content of the node `<Inner>`, but only if it is not numeric. Or in other words: I only want to select it, if it contains at least one character. So the result should only be `123ABC`.

My SQL code currently looks as follows.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @xml XML;
SET @string = 
  '<XML><Data><Outer><Inner>123ABC</Inner></Outer><Outer><Inner>-123</Inner></Outer><Outer><Inner>123</Inner></Outer></Data></XML>';
SET @xml = @string;
SELECT @xml;


SELECT h.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('XML') AS Statements(nodes)
OUTER APPLY @xml.nodes('Data/Outer/Inner') AS Data(h)
```

The query selects all nodes, that is, `123ABC`, `-123`, and `123`. However, I only want to select `123ABC`. To get this to work with my real example, I need to adapt the `OUTER APPLY` line:

```
OUTER APPLY @xml.nodes('Data/Outer/Inner') AS Data(h)
```

I am pretty sure that my goal can be achieved by applying a filter as follows.

```
@xml.nodes('Data/Outer/Inner[FILTER]')
```

However, I could not find anything that works.

**UPDATE:** The filter criterion can be stated in more detail as follows. Only elements that contain at least one letter should be shown. So also the following values should not be shown for instance: -1.5, 1.5, -33

Comment: another filter option for letters : @xml.nodes('/XML/Data/Outer/Inner[upper-case(.) ne lower-case(.)]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
//Inner[not(.>0)]/text()
```

outputs "123ABC".

Comment: can you explain what this does exactly? It selects only nodes where the value is not higher than 0. And that means that alphanumeric values are selected. But negative numbes would also be selected right?

Comment: maybe this would be even better: `[not(.>0)][not(.<0)]`. What do you think?

Comment: It evaluates and selects inner nodes which content is not higher than 0 (return false to the test). And yes for your proposition if you have negative values. Or `//Inner[not(.>0 or .<0)]/text()`.

Answer (score 1):

***IF*** your XML data is actually meant to be the below (note the ending `XML` tag, which is missing in your example):

```xml
<XML>
  <Data>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>123ABC</Inner>
    </Outer>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>123</Inner>
    </Outer>
  </Data>
</XML>
```

Then you could use a `LIKE` expression to check it has a character that isn't a numerical value:

```
SELECT X.I.value('text()[1]','varchar(6)') AS [Inner]
FROM @xml.nodes('/XML/Data/Outer/Inner') AS X(I)
WHERE X.I.value('text()[1]','varchar(6)') LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

*If* the XML you have provided is correct, you won't be able to use XQUERY, as it is not valid XML, due to the `XML` node not being closed.

Edit: Bit of conjecture based on the comments (the goal is still a little unclear), however, perhaps:

```
SELECT X.I.value('text()[1]','varchar(6)') AS [Inner]
FROM @xml.nodes('/XML/Data/Outer/Inner') AS X(I)
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(38,0),X.I.value('text()[1]','varchar(6)')) IS NULL;
```

Or, based on this statement *"Character as in letter."*, simply:

```
SELECT X.I.value('text()[1]','varchar(6)') AS [Inner]
FROM @xml.nodes('/XML/Data/Outer/Inner') AS X(I)
WHERE X.I.value('text()[1]','varchar(6)') LIKE '%[A-z]%';
```

Comment: I closed the XML node now. It was a typo.

Comment: Negative numbers are also in your result. I added this to my question. Can you enhance your solution to also exclude negative numbers?

Comment: Knowing that that was a scenario would have helped, @beta . What about decimals (e.g. `<Inner>7.5</inner>`)? Providing all the scenarios helps us help you.

Comment: I know. Sorry. Didn't think of that earlier. The rule should be: Only show alphanumeric values. So values that contain at least one letter.

Comment: `<Inner>7.5</inner>` should not be in the result set.

Comment: @beta  `1` *is* a character too, as it `-`.

Comment: Character as in letter.

Comment: So something like `123-456@789` or `123 456` should not be displayed, @beta ?

Comment: This yields the following error: `'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`. I guess my SQL Server Version (or the set compatibility level) is too low.

Comment: The last one looks good. I will delete my comments now and add my extensions to the question.

Comment: @beta If you're using **unsupported** software you should really be tagging that version. `TRY_CONVERT` is available in all supported versions of SQL Server (including those in extended support). if you don't tell us you're using unsupported software, the users here will assume you're using a supported one and write answers that will work in any of the supported versions; but may well fail in older ones. `TRY_CONVERT` was added in SQL Server 2012, which means you're using SQL Server 2008R2 or prior.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU11) (KB4527378) - 13.0.5598.27 (X64)

Comment: Then `TRY_CONVERT` is supported, @beta . Are you perhaps in Compatibility mode 100?

Comment: do you have any idea which solution (yours or the one below) is more efficient in terms of execution?

Comment: That would likely be easier for you to test, @beta . We only have a scalar variable here, so there's going to be little (at best a couple of nano seconds) to no performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

It might be as simple as this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<XML>
  <Data>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>123ABC</Inner>
    </Outer>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>-123</Inner>
    </Outer>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>-123 with blah</Inner>
    </Outer>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>1.23</Inner>
    </Outer>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>123</Inner>
    </Outer>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>-1.5</Inner>
    </Outer>
    <Outer>
      <Inner>-33</Inner>
    </Outer>
  </Data>
</XML>';
```

--the query

```
SELECT numericInner.value('.','varchar(100)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/XML/Data/Outer/Inner[empty(. cast as xs:float?)]') A(numericInner);
```

The idea in short:

- We use `.nodes()` to retrieve a derived set of `<Inner>` elements
- But we add a *predicate*: We are looking for elements only, if their content cannot be casted to float. In this case, the XQuery-cast is `empty()`.

### UPDATE

Thanks to @lptr's hint I want to add, that a value of `1.E+2` might disturb this in very special situations (due to scientific notation). But you can use a cast to `decimal`:

```
select cast('1.E+2' as xml).query('.[empty(. cast as xs:float?)]') AS CanBeCastedThereforeEmpty
      ,cast('1.E+2' as xml).query('.[empty(. cast as xs:decimal?)]') AS CannotBeCastedReturnedAsString
```

Comment: scientific notation could cause conflicts (depending on the requirements): `select cast('1.E+2' as xml).query('.[empty(number())]')`

Comment: @lptr, that's true... Thx for the hint... With `. cast as xs:decimal?` this seem to work...

Comment: nice!! a different approach, would be to check for inequality between upper() and lower() ... select cast('1.1A2' as xml).query('.[upper-case(.) ne lower-case(.)]') (although punctuation marks in the middle of the string are still a grey area for the requirements of the question)